# Delete Records from multiple tables in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a SQL script which performs delete operation from multiple tables based on say employee ids:

```
DELETE FROM EMP_ADDRESS where EMP_ID in (EMP_IDS);
DELETE FROM EMP_DETAILS where EMP_ID in (EMP_IDS);
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE where EMP_ID in (EMP_IDS);
```

Is there a way to call the sql script from Spring batch by passing the employee ids? I tried an alternate approach where in the writer i get the ids and delete from the tables as below:

```
public class DeleteEmployeeData implements ItemWriter<EmployeeData>{

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
@Override
public void write(List<? extends EmployeeData> items) throws Exception {

for(EmployeeData item : items){
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.DELETE_EMP_ADDRESS,item.getEmployeeId());
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.DELETE_EMP_DETAILS,item.getEmployeeId());
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.DELETE_EMPLOYEES,item.getEmployeeId());
}
}
}
```

This works. But i wanted to know if there is a better approach than this?

Comment: `Is there a way to call the sql script from Spring batch by passing the employee ids?`: How do you pass the employee IDs to your job? Is it via job parameters?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine : I have a reader that reads these ids from DB and then filters the ids based on some input i recieve in a CSV. The filtered list of ids are sent as output in XML externally. Finally i have to delete the filtered records from my DB. The delete SQL scripts are already with me. But i wanted to know if it possible to invoke the SQL script from my batch application?

Comment: ok thanks, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach with a chunk oriented step looks good to me:

- The reader reads IDs
- A processor filters IDs
- And a composite writer with two writers: one to write xml and another one to delete items

Comment: Thanks for your response. so the writer to delete items should do be in this way only right @Override
public void write(List<? extends EmployeeData> items) throws Exception {

for(EmployeeData item : items){
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.DELETE_EMP_ADDRESS,item.getEmployeeId());
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.DELETE_EMP_DETAILS,item.getEmployeeId());
jdbcTemplate.update(SQLConstants.DELETE_EMPLOYEES,item.getEmployeeId());
} Or is there a way to call a sql script file which has all the delete queries by passing the employee ids?